# Making azure hosted website part of company intranet (singe sign on)

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on, intranet

We are considering deploying some of our intranet web applications to Azure. The web applications are built using ASP.NET MVC. Source code is available, it is fully under our control. All our company machines are Windows 7 or up, part of a windows domain, sitting behind proxy a server. Users are registered in AD. **What authentication technology would you recommend for a secure and convenient login experience?** We prefer to save the employees from creating, remembering, typing in yet another username/pwd. Single-Sign-On is wonderful for the users. Can we achieve something similar? Up to what extent do we have to compromise on the convenience?

Reasons to move to Azure: Azure does not have the bureaucratic deployment obstacles that our intranet has. Furthermore, deploying webapps to Azure is just soooo easy and wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Active Directory extends on-premises AD into the cloud, enabling users to use their organizational account to not only sign in to their domain-joined devices and company resources, but also all of the web and SaaS applications 
(office 365) needed for their job.
Federated Single Sign-On  for applications that support SAML 2.0, WS-Federation, openID connect.
Password based for apps with a html sign on page and Existing SSO using ADFS.